# Powershell command line parameters Null or Empty

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script test.ps1 as follows:

```
param(     
      $a = "ValueA"
)
```

now if call it from the command line from my msbuild project file as follows

.\test.ps1 -a ""
.\test.ps1 -a $null

it does not assign the default value "ValueA" to $a. I would like to assign the default "Value" to $a even if the user pass it null or empty values. I know i can use *if* construct but i was wondering if there is a quick shorter way to achieve this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no shorter way than *if* construct for such cases (*editor clarification: such cases are cases where you **explicitly** specify the parameter to be something other than the default in the call*).

Comment: I agree with this answer.  You are explicitly saying you want the parameter to be `null` when calling it.  If you want the parameter when `null`, to be the default, you need to write some code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

param(
 $a = "ValueA"
)

$a = ("ValueA",$a)[[int][bool]$a]

Comment: Okay, so it's not really shorter.